# Limit of Integral About a Point

Tags: integration, analysis, limits

I'm wondering how one would go about proving rigorously the following statement:

Suppose one has an infinitely differentiable (I'm not sure one needs this, but I'm thinking about the Taylor expansion of $f$), continuous, single-valued function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ where $[a,b] \subset{\Bbb{R}}$. For some $c \in{[a,b]}$, prove $$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\int_{c-\epsilon}^{c+\epsilon}f(x)\, dx = 0.$$ I should note that I'm a physicist and it's been some time since I took analysis in ug. Much thanks if anyone can help.

Comment: It doesn't... it approximately equals $2\epsilon f(c).$  And as epsilon goes to zero the integral goes to 0.  Are you thinking of something more like $\int \delta (x-c) f(x) \ dx = f(c)$?

Comment: I completely wrote the question wrong, I meant show it equals 0. Apologies, I had some other idea my head when writing. Ill change it. Would you mind showing your method of obtaining 0? @DougM

Comment: The limit is $0$ even if $f$ is just bounded on $[a,b]$. Does that give you an idea of an approach?

Comment: @AntonioVargas it does actually. Could I perhaps pick out the maximum of $f$ over $[a,b]$ and show this integral goes to $0$, implying the above integral is $0$ as well since it's less than the latter over $[a,b]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a function $f$ that is bounded on a neighbourhood of $c$, say, $|f(x)|<M$ for all $x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)$, then $\left|\displaystyle\int_{c-\epsilon}^{c+\epsilon}f(x)dx\right|\leq\displaystyle\int_{c-\epsilon}^{c+\epsilon}|f(x)|dx\leq 2M\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon<\delta$. Now the result follows by Squeeze Theorem because of that $2M\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ as $\epsilon\downarrow 0$.

Note that $f$ is continuous at $x=c$ implies that $f$ is bounded on a neighbourhood of $c$.